# Как сохранить данные в кэш андроид приложения, чтобы они обновлялись при повторном подключении интернета?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, кэширование, jsoup

я создал приложение, которое получает данные из сайта через библиотеку JSOUP и записывает их в определенные формы(объекты). После отключения интернета мои данные исчезают при повторном открытии приложения. Мне нужно, чтобы они не удалялись до повторного включения интерента. Я пишу на Java в android studio. И так мой вопрос: как мне сохранить полученные данные и где?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохранять надо в постоянную память телефона (у вас, видимо, только в оперативку пишется).

Вышеописанное можно сделать по разному:

1. Сохранять сам HTML полученный прямо в файл (и оттуда его, соответстенно, считывать когда надо).
2. Сохранять полученные структурированные данные в файл (например в JSON перевести)
3. Структурированные данные в БД записать.

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали-)) Попробую указанные пути...